# find dataframe values that are present in list in columns pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, django-views, isin

I've created DataFrame using pandas.

[image: Here is DataFrame]

I'm Showing Map with custom Markers Using these dataframe.

I want to filter the Map on the basis of frontend side filter selection of dropdown Product_Type.

[image: Here is the filter DropDown of Product_Type]

when I was Selecting any of these 2 Product_Type Options **(Bag OR Bulk)** from the Product_Type dropdown then its showing proper result.

but The Problem I was facing, when I was selecting **Select All** Option then its giving an error `only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]`.

In the Dataframe the Product_Type contains in list. How do I get All Values for Product_Type?

Here is the html file code:

```
<form action="" method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                <label for="select_routeid_plant" class="mb-2">Plant Code</label>
                <select name="plant_code" id="select_routeid_plant" class="selectedVal custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option value="all">Select All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                <label for="select_routeid_destination" class="mb-2">Destination</label>
                <select name="destination_code" id="select_routeid_destination" class="selectedVal custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option value="all">Select All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                <label for="select_product_type" class="mb-2">Product Type</label>
                <select name="product_type" id="select_product_type" class="selectedProductType custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option value="all">Select All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-2 pl-0">
                <label for="select_month" class="mb-2">Month</label>
                <select name="month" id="select_month" class="selectedProductType custom-select custom-select-sm">
                    <option value="all">Select All</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary px-4 mt-4" value="Filter" onclick="showRoute()">
    </div>
</form>
```

Here is the Views.py code

```
if request.method == "POST":
    plant_code = request.POST.get("plant_code")
    destination_code = request.POST.get("destination_code")
    product = request.POST.get("product_type")
   
    if plant_code == 'all':
         plant_code = list(file_data['Route_Id'].unique())
    else:
         plant_code = plant_code.split("*")
            
    if destination_code =='all':
         destination_code = list(file_data['Route_Id'].unique())
    else:
         destination_code = destination_code.split("*")
            
    if product =='all':
         product = list(file_data['Product_Type'].unique())
    else:
         product = product.split("*")


    
    post_data = file_data[(file_data['Route_Id'].isin(plant_code)) &
                                (file_data['Product_Type'].isin(product))  &
                                (file_data['Route_Id'].isin(destination_code))]
```

Comment: can you include the full stack trace and an [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if possible

Comment: Hello @will-wright-eng thanks for your reply. 
can you check now?

Comment: From my point of view the code looks correct.
Check that the 'all' condition is recognized.
If the condition is not true, you would pass the value obtained from the request to the isin function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

created the following dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'B':[['Bag'], ['Bag'], ['Bag', 'Bulk'], ['Bag'], ['Bag']]})
```

Output

```
   A            B
0  1        [Bag]
1  2        [Bag]
2  3  [Bag, Bulk]
3  4        [Bag]
4  5        [Bag]
```

when printing the first value of column B I get the type:

```
print(type(df.loc[0, 'B']))#<class 'list'>
```

you have to check your type:

```
print(type(file_data.loc[0, 'Product_Type']))#??????
```

According to the [isin](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) documentation, a list with values is substituted into the function.

Since in my example this is a list, I additionally enclose it in square brackets:

```
print(df['B'].isin([['Bag', 'Bulk']]))
```

Output

```
0    False
1    False
2     True
3    False
4    False
```

If I try to do something like `list(file_data['Product_Type'].unique())` with my `df['B'].unique()` column, it will fail with an error: `TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'`. That is, you need to understand what `file_data['Product_Type'].unique()` returns?

**The same error that you get occurs when passing a string to isin instead of a list:`print(df['B'].isin('Bag')):`**

```
TypeError: only list-like objects are allowed to be passed to isin(), you passed a [str]
```